Error using Sqflite_fii in Flutter databaseFactoryFfi
I trying to get flutter working with sqlite but i can't get out of the following  errors

Error: Undefined name 'databaseFactoryFfi'. _databasdatabaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
Eror: Setter not found: '_databasdatabaseFactory'. _databasdatabaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
Error: Setter not found: 'eFactory'. eFactory = null;
Has anyone experimented this? Can someone help?

I installed several times sqflite, sqflite 3, sqflite_ffi... ang got the databasefactoryffi error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Add the following dependencies to your pubspec.yaml file:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  sqflite: ^2.0.0+4
  path: ^1.8.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  sqflite_ffi: ^2.0.0+4

